# unresolved class PlaceAutocompleteFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, placeautocompletefragment

This is my .xml file
I added the PlaceAutocompleteFragment but its shows unresolved class PlaceAutocompleteFragment. I cheched the dependency file all things are added.

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

This is my gradle.
I don't know where is my mistake please verify my code and tell where is the error.

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    testImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add this dependency, it is used for google places

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.8.0'
```